# Document band Occupying white space when not printed

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to print a set of information on the bottom of my document's first page (right after detail band). Since the information printed on detail is too large, the document creates a pagination to display the rest of the information, but independent of what I use (Group,ColumnFooter,PageFooter,etc) to print the information tha should be printed on the first page only, this band keeps occupying a white space on consequent pages.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should post the small sample (*jrxml*) to reproduce the problem. The image illustrating the problem can help to understand the issue better

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy group that would break with every record, but only while we are on the first page.
Such group would not have a group header or footer, but would use minHeightToStartNewPage with a value that would match the taller page footer required on the first page.
The group expression would look like the following:

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 ? $V{REPORT_COUNT} : null
```

This dummy group would cause a page break to occur upper on the first page, leaving more space for a larger page footer.

Now, the second trick is to place content in the page footer section, but at a position having a negative Y coordinate. By doing so, you can keep the height of the page footer section small, while being able to render content above it.
This content having negative Y inside the page footer would be printed conditionally, only on the first page, using the printWhenExpression.